# react js + reactstrap + bootstrap-select

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-select, reactstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to use the [react](/questions/tagged/react) + bootstrap + bootstrap-select. I've successfully changed the select dropdown to bootstrap-select but the click event's aren't getting triggered.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, createRef,forwardRef } from 'react';
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Col, Row, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css';

const AddPModal = ({ addPModalShow, hideModal }) => {

  const handleSelectPicker = ()=>{
    console.log($('#add_tag').selectpicker());
  }
    return (
      <Modal size="lg" isOpen={addPModalShow} centered={true} onOpened={handleSelectPicker}>
      <ModalHeader>Add New Prospect</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <Form>
          <Row form>
            <Col md={6}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="add_tag">tag</Label>
                <select name="tag" id="add_tag" className="form-control">
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option><option>3</option>
                </select>
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="primary">Save</Button>
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={hideModal}>Cancel</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
    );
}

export default AddPModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<select name="tag" id="add_tag" className="form-control selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option><option>3</option>
</select>
...
```

Add `selectpicker` class to your `select` elements to auto-initialize bootstrap-select.
For more info [click here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/#:%7E:text=Add%20the%20selectpicker%20class%20to%20your%20select%20elements%20to%20auto-initialize%20bootstrap-select.)

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    $("#mySelect").selectpicker("refresh");
}, []);
```

To initialize your selectpicker element (it will render properly) - it will not work as the jquery event handlers are not called (required for all functionality.

Best is to avoid jquery in your react project.